# Is there a simpler way to input multi-line data from a fixed point in a text file?

Tags: sas

I have control data that tells me the line number where a block of multi-line data starts, and the block in terminated by a semicolon (`;`)

I am currently using `input #` and looping to find the block termination.

Is there a simpler input directive that would eliminate the need to loop ?

```
filename textdata temp;

data _null_;
  file textdata;
  input;
  put _infile_;
  datalines4;
1
2
3
4
d e f g
h i j k
l m n o
;
4
5
6
7
p
 q
  r
   s
;
;;;;

data marks;
  linenum =  5; output;
  linenum = 13; output;
run;

data extract;
  infile textdata;

  length block $150;

  do index = 1 by 1 while (not lastmark);
    set marks end=lastmark;

    input #linenum;
    do while (_infile_ ne ';');
      block = catx(' ', block, _infile_);
      input;
    end;

    output;
    block = '';
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file line by line and check whether or not you are inside of a "block" or not.

You can keep the list of START lines in a dataset, but for a small list it is probably easier to just keep it in a macro variable.

First let's create an example text file:

```
filename textdata temp;
options parmcards=textdata;
parmcards4;
1
2
3
4
d e f g
h i j k
l m n o
;
4
5
6
7
p
 q
  r
   s
;
;;;;
```

Create dataset

```
%let marks=5 13 ;

data extract;
  length index inblock start last 8 block $150 ;
  retain inblock 0 start last block ;
  infile textdata end=eof;
  input ;
  if _infile_=';' then do;
    if inblock then output;
    block=' ';
    inblock=0;
    start=.;
  end;
  if _n_ in (&marks) then do;
    index+1;
    start=_n_;
    inblock=1;
  end;
  if inblock then block=catx(' ',block,_infile_);
  last=_n_;
  if eof and inblock then output;
  drop inblock;
run;
```

Results

```
OBS    index    start    last    block

 1       1         5       7     d e f g h i j k l m n o
 2       2        13      16     p q r s
```